# One directive to call and include other directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have a directive, `app.directive('schedule', function(){..})`. As it can be assumed, each `schedule` would have multiple `shifts` and each `shift` has multiple `tasks`. I want each of these items to be their own directive.

BUT I don't want to have to include ALL of them when I load the page. Instead, I want to have one `app.js` that is injected as a dependency into the page that I load, and then inside this `app.js`, I inject all the other dependencies.

This is not a problem when I call `factories` and `services`, but I can't figure out how to do this for `directives` as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you include all of your Directives in your module, you'll have access to them. You'd nest them inside your directive templates just like you would anywhere else in your markup.

Comment: That's the thing. I don't want to do that; I am lazy-loading my files as I need them. So if I go to a specific `route`, then I load `app.js` and I want that file to then load everything else.